# RG flow trajctory plot using StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, vector, streams

I have three flow (beta-function) equations:

1. $\frac{dA}{dl}=-(B^2+C^2)$,
2. $\frac{dB}{dl}=(2-4A)B$,
3. $\frac{dC}{dl}=(2-A)C$,

where $A=\pi/(2\arccos(-(x+y)/2)$, $B=(x+y)/2$ and $C=(x-y)/2$.

I can make a 3-D flow diagram using `StreamPlot3D` in $A{-}B{–}C$ space, but how can I make it in a 2-D $x-y$ plane (because that one will be easier to analyze)?

Mathematica code:

```
StreamPlot3D[{-(b^2+c^2), (2-4a)b, (2-a)c}, {a,0,3}, {b,0,4}, {c,-3,3},
 StreamMarkers -> "Arrow"]

a = π/(2 ArcCos[-(x + y)/2]);
b = (x + y)/2;
c = (x - y)/2;
```

Comment: Note that $a=\pi/(2 \arccos(-b))$ so the system is overdetermined. Equivalently the variables $x,y$ are not independent but satisfy a constraint $f(x,y)=0$. So what exactly do you mean by a 2d plot?

Comment: I meant to draw a flow diagram in x-y plane

Comment: There is no x-y plane. x and y are not independent.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform   `x==b+c, y==b-c`,  and `a==Pi/(2* ArcCos[-b]`, it means that `x,y` are independent.

Comment: @cvgmt Not really. The equations in the OP are compatible only along the line $$\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)+\frac{\pi  (x+y) (\pi -\arccos(-\frac{1}{2} (x+y)))}{\sqrt{4-(x+y)^2} \arccos(-\frac{1}{2} (x+y))^3}=0$$You can check this using the code `{a'[L], b'[L], c'[L]} == {-(b[L]^2 + c[L]^2), (2 - 4 a[L]) b[L], (2 - a[L]) c[L]} /. {a -> (\[Pi]/(2 ArcCos[-(x[#] + y[#])/2]) &), b -> ((x[#] + y[#])/2 &), c -> ((x[#] - y[#])/2 &)} // Thread

           %[[1]] /. Solve[%[[2 ;; 3]], {x'[L], y'[L]}][[1]] // Simplify`